# Laravel 5.x save two models with relationship in one form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I studied the [Laravel Intermediate Task tutorial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart-intermediate) and now I want to create a more complicated app based from it.

I am creating a daily log app to study model dependencies. I have three models: `User`, `DayLog` and `Task`.

- `User`s have many `DayLog`s.
- **`DayLog`s *can* have many `Tasks` (optional).**
- `User`s and `DayLog`'s relationship and CRUD are working OK which were directly lifted from the tutorial.

Now I want to save a `DayLog` with a `Task` which I have a difficulty in achieving.

Here are my models indicating the relationship discussed before:

```
// User.php
public function dayLogs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(DayLog::class);
}

// DayLog.php
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
public function task()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
}

// Task.php
public function dayLog()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(DayLog::class);
}
```

Currently I am developing in the back end. I am trying to associate a `Task` to this `DayLog` being saved:

```
// DayLogController.php
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'daylog_name' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);

    // Create dummy Task
    $task = new Task();
    $task->name = "My new task ".date('Ymd');

    // Save Task to the current DayLog - NOK
    $request->daylog()->tasks()->create([
        'task_name' => $task->name,
    ]);

    // Save DayLog to User - OK
    $request->user()->daylogs()->create([
        'name' => $request->daylog_name,
    ]);

    return redirect('/daylogs');
}
```

This shows an error:

> BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
>
> Method daylog does not exist.

I do not understand why `user()` is in `$request` while `daylog()` is not.

- Basically I would like to successfully save the inline `Task` as a part of the `DayLog` inside the method above.
- Is this not achievable with native Eloquent methods and if yes, should I look into the query builder? If not, please share how to achieve this with Eloquent.

I hope you can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added the methods `user()`, `daylog()`, `task()` to your models, however you are trying to use them on `Request $request`. `$request` contains only data you sent him from front end, it has nothing to do with your database. You should use these methods on your model entities that you get either from existing (`$daylog = Daylog::where('name', $request->daylog_name)->first()`, for example) or new (`$daylog = Daylog::create(['name' => $request->daylog_name])` and then you can use them like this `$daylog->tasks()->create(['task_name' => 'My new task '.date('Ymd')])` and `$user->daylogs()->save($daylog)`.

The reason why method `user()` works on `$request` is that you use default laravel authentication and this is possible to get currently authenticated user in there this way so you can get current user user entity like `$user = $request->user()`. It is important to understand that this method `user()` you use on `$request` is default laravel method and not the same that you would use on `$daylog->user()`.

Here is the documentation links you might find useful:

[Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)

[Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication)

Comment: Thanks! Next question, when I fetch a `DayLog`, how come its `Task`s are not included (ie `$this->daylogs->getAllByUser($request->user())`)? Wherein they're not available when I do `{{ $daylog->tasks }}` in the front end. Is this the normal behavior where I should fetch the `Task` separately as well given the `DayLog` foreign key?

Comment: Sorry to flood you, I really want to learn this and these specific questions and I guess you are available right now. Regarding Laravel authentication, as I understood from the tutorial, `User` was introduced to filter `Task`s by legit `User`s in the DB; my question is do I need to do it (ie add authentication for `DayLog`s and their `Task`s) for `Task`s that belong to my `DayLog`s or is that overkill because the foreign key constraints will be responsible for that?

Comment: When you fetch model Eloquent doesn't fetch all of it's relationships, so if you need some of them on your front end, you can override `toArray()` method of your model or add a new one and call it before sending, in which you create array(s) of relations that you need to send and append them to `$this->toArray()` array before returning. Like `$arrayDaylog = $this->toArray()`, `$tasks = $this->tasks()->toArray()`, `$arrayDaylog['tasks'] = $tasks`, `return $arrayDaylog`

Comment: "When you fetch model Eloquent doesn't fetch all of it's relationships." Thank you, this is what I needed. Unfortunately the documentation does not explicitly mention this.

Comment: Also, give it a read: [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: As far as I get your problem right, foreign key constraints will be just enough

Comment: Another one, I know I can make DB queries in the model and repository. But what if I want to make a method to get `Task`s of a `DayLog`, which repository is best to put this in: `DayLogRepository` (since I access a `DayLog` object) or in `TaskRepository` (because Eloquent does not fetch all dependencies, fetch an object needed from its respective Repository)? The latter will require me to make the `DayLogController` constructor to have `TaskRepository` as a parameter for initialization.

Comment: Consider repository as a collection that holds entities and can filter them in some way and return back based on your needs. So your repository should return collection of entities, probably filtered by some condition (belonging to `DayLog` that you need in your example) and it would be strange if `DayLogRepository` returned collection of `Taks`s, so `TaskRepository` is your choice

Comment: You don't need that `DayLogRepository` parameter, just access your `Task` model `daylog()` method in `TaskRepository`

Answer (score 0):

When updating the belongsTo method, use [associate()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships) method:

```
$task = new Task();
$task->name = "My new task ".date('Ymd');  

$request->user()->daylogs()->->create([
           'name' => $request->daylog_name,
  ])->associate($task);
```

Comment: I get `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::associate()` which is weird because I assume this is an inherited method from the `Model` superclass or should I explicitly define this in `DayLog.php`?